# How to remove extra commas from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes and if one is checked, I'm appending the checkbox value to a input field elsewhere on the page.  If a checkbox is unchecked, I'm removing the value from the hidden input field.  What is happening is if the values are being added and removed just fine but they are leaving a series of commas behind when a check box is checked, unchecked, checked, unchecked, etc.

A) should I worry about it
B) if yes, how should I alter my add/append routine (see below) or is there a better way to do what I'm doing?  I'd prefer to end up with a clean list like `0_1,0_2,41_4` opposed to `0_1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,0_2,,,,41_4,,,,`.

```
    <input type="text" value="0_1,0_2,41_4" id="EOStatus_SelLayers" />

    // example of dataset:  '0_1,0_2,41_4'; 
    if ( xyz.hasClass("icon-check-empty") ) {
        var existing_str = $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val();
            if (existing_str==null || existing_str==""){
                //add
                $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val(id);
            }
            else {
                //append    
                $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val( existing_str + ',' + id);                 
            }
    }
    else {
        $(xyz).removeClass("icon-check").addClass("icon-check-empty");
        var old_str = $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val();
        var new_str = old_str.replace(','+id,'');
        var new_str = old_str.replace(id,'');
        $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val(new_str);
    }
```

In the else statement, I could do something like this:

```
var new_str = old_str.replace(id,'');  
var new_str = old_str.replace(',,',',');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the id with an empty string and then replace any extraneous commas.

There are three places you can end up with an extraneous comma:

1. A double comma somewhere in the middle (needs to be replaced with a single comma)
2. A leading comma (needs to be removed)
3. A trailing comma (needs to be removed)

You can address all three cases with these two replace operations:

```
.replace(/,,/g, ",").replace(/^,|,$/g, "");
```

Which in place could look like this:

```
else {
    $(xyz).removeClass("icon-check").addClass("icon-check-empty");
    var old_str = $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val();
    var new_str = old_str.replace(id,'').replace(/,,/g, ",").replace(/^,|,$/g, "");
    $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val(new_str);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about leading or trailing commas.  Good catch.  Testing solution now.

Comment: Okay, that is very pretty.  New snippet for me.  Will aprove when SO says enough time has elapsed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery - a simpler approach would be simple re-set the input value each time a change was made to checkboxes? Simply concat the ID of each :checked input... If you're using a custom lib to change the appearance of the checkboxes I'm sure there's on-change event triggers that would allow the following to work.

Alternatively you should be able to edit to suit your specific needs.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
    var newVal = [];

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        newVal.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val(newVal.join(','));
});
```

Or, in the case you're using images:

```
$('[class^="icon-check"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var newVal = [];

    $('.icon-check').each(function() {
        newVal.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $(this).toggleClass('icon-check-empty');
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-check');

    $('#EOStatus_SelLayers').val(newVal.join(','));
});
```

Disclaimer: not tested - but looks like it should work.

Comment: I'm not really using check boxes, I'm using an image looks like a larger check box (its larger and easier for my clients to visually see it).  Otherwise, your solution does look good.  I'll try it when I complete my project.  I'm new to .push so it does look intriguing.

Comment: array push is an ecmascript3 standard and works in IE5.5+ along with any common browser. more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push.

I've edited the above to give a sample on how you could use with images.

Disclaimer: not tested - but looks like it should work.

Comment: the solution you have now is different than what you had earlier so I tried this one, too.  Using the .push and .splice, I decided I no longer needed the hidden input and was able to do everything I needed in much smaller code base, too.  Thanks for opening my eyes.  :)